# How do I upload to an imgur user's account

Tags: c#, oauth, imgur

I am able to upload anonymous images to imgur using the api like this:

```
public static void UploadImage()
{
    Image image = GetImage();
    string base64 = Util.ImageToBase64(image);

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientID);

        NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
        data["image"] = base64;
        data["type"] = "base64";

        byte[] responsePayload = client.UploadValues("https://api.imgur.com/3/image/", "POST", data);
        string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responsePayload);
    }
}
```

It's uploading to a completely random url. I couldn't find any documentation which showed how to do this, but is it possible to upload an image to a *user's* account so that it shows in their uploaded images?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of sending a `"CLIENT-ID"` header, you need to send a `"BEARER"` header, with the token that you recieve by using imgur's [oauth 2 api](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2#making_request). This allows you to post images to a user's account, whereas before I only providewd the client id, which allowed me to post anonymous images. The code looks like this:

```
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "BEARER " + accessToken);
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to Ivan Chub's answer...  I just got stuck uploading to my imgur account in python for a minute until I tried changing BEARER to Bearer.

```
req.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + imgur_access_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

If using **curl** from command line

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" -F "image=@PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE_FILE" https://api.imgur.com/3/upload
```

More info on https://planspace.org/2013/01/13/upload-images-to-your-imgur-account/